# Efficient way to cluster a timeline OR reconstruct a batch number

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, group-by, sql-server-2017

I'm working on a large dataset (150k / day) of a tester database. Each row contains data about a specific test of the product. Each tester inserts the results of his test.

I want to do some measurements like pass-fail-rate over a shift per product and tester. The problem is there are no batch numbers assigned so I can't select this easy.

Considering the given subselect of the whole table:

```
 id   tBegin                orderId   
------------------------------------
 1    2018-10-20 00:00:05   1
 2    2018-10-20 00:05:15   1
 3    2018-10-20 01:00:05   1
 10   2018-10-20 10:03:05   3
 12   2018-10-20 11:04:05   8
 20   2018-10-20 14:15:05   3
 37   2018-10-20 18:12:05   1
```

My goal is it to cluster the data to the following

```
 id   tBegin                orderId   pCount 
--------------------------------------------
 1    2018-10-20 00:00:05   1         3
 10   2018-10-20 10:03:05   3         1
 12   2018-10-20 11:04:05   8         1
 20   2018-10-20 14:15:05   3         1
 37   2018-10-20 18:12:05   1         1
```

A simple `GROUP BY orderID` won't do the trick, so I came upwith the following

```
SELECT 
  MIN(c.id) AS id,
  MIN(c.tBegin) AS tBegin,
  c.orderId,
  COUNT(*) AS pCount
FROM (
    SELECT t2.id, t2.tBegin, t2.orderId,
      ( SELECT TOP 1 t.id
        FROM history t
        WHERE t.tBegin > t2.tBegin
          AND t.orderID <> t2.orderID
          AND <restrict date here further>
        ORDER BY t.tBegin 
       ) AS nextId
    FROM history t2 
) AS c
WHERE <restrict date here>
GROUP BY c.orderID, c.nextId
```

I left out the `WHERE`s that select the correct date and tester.
This works, but it seams very inefficient. I have worked with small databases, but I'm new to SQL Server 2017.

I appreciate your help very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions for this:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (id INT, tBegin DATETIME, orderId INT);
INSERT INTO @t VALUES
(1 , '2018-10-20 00:00:05', 1),
(2 , '2018-10-20 00:05:15', 1),
(3 , '2018-10-20 01:00:05', 1),
(10, '2018-10-20 10:03:05', 3),
(12, '2018-10-20 11:04:05', 8),
(20, '2018-10-20 14:15:05', 3),
(37, '2018-10-20 18:12:05', 1);

WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT *, CASE WHEN orderId = LAG(orderId) OVER (ORDER BY tBegin) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS chg
    FROM @t
), cte2 AS (
    SELECT *, SUM(chg) OVER(ORDER BY tBegin) AS grp
    FROM cte1
), cte3 AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY tBegin) AS rn
    FROM cte2
)
SELECT *
FROM cte3
WHERE rn = 1
```

- The first cte assigns a "change flag" to each row where the value changed
- The second cte uses a running sum to convert 1s and 0s to a number which can be used to group rows
- Finally you number rows within each group and select first row per group

[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9ecdb330397ee62bb49f6f401ed091a0)

Answer (score 0):

You can use cumulative approach :

```
select min(id) as id, max(tBegin), orderid, count(*) 
from (select h.*,
             row_number() over (order by id) as seq1,
             row_number() over (partition by orderid order by id) as seq2
      from history h
     ) h
group by orderid, (seq1 - seq2)
order by id;
```